# Random Data in datatable cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Is it possible to set unique data using datatable instead of harcoding,
I need to  contruct a crud UI framework where I will be creating a records then verify that records is been fetched , then updating it and verify records is been updated

```
Given user wants to register for new account with the following details
      | firstName             | Micheal           |
      | lastName              | Dre               |
      | email                 | test@dddd.com     |
      | phoneNumber           | 5555555555        |
```

So instead of hardcoding , as the records need to be unique for every test run
Planned to user faker java library , not able to figure what is best apporoch to get this , searched varioud forum but not able to contruct same

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of designing scenario doesn't looks good. You should check for other ways. However, one of the possible solution for what you are looking for is possible with [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) using [parameter](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_configuration.html#parameter-interpolation) with `rnd` prefix. Your step may look like below:

```
Given user wants to register for new account with the following details
      | firstName             | Auto${rnd:aaaaa}         |
      | lastName              | ${rnd:aaa}               |
      | email                 | Auto-${rnd:aaa}@dddd.com |
      | phoneNumber           | ${rnd:9999999999}        |
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding random data using a datatable, you can do so in your step definition. Or create a helper method that creates a random user and call that from your step definition.

The .feature file is intended to describe the behaviour of the system. If you just need a random user to be logged in, the details of that user are not important to describe that behaviour.

So, your step would be:
`Given user wants to register for new account`

Your step definitions would be something like:

```
@Given("user wants to register for new account")
public void userRegistersForNewAccount() {
    randomUser();
}
```

and you will have a helper method `randomUser()` that returns a random user.